# how a class works

Tags: python, class

I am trying to figure out a really simple problem but still I can't quite get how a class works. For example, in case I wanted to create a class called "Friend" with an attribute called "name", does this mean I will have to give a variable called "name"before anything else ? Then how can i define the constructor to allow the specification of "name"? Is this code nonsense? Thanks in advance for any response

```
class Friend:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.set_name(name)


    def set_name(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11720

Answer (score 8):

That code is not nonsense as in it accomplishes what you want to accomplish.  It is not very pythonic, though.  There are no reason you should use getter or setters.  Just access the attributes directly. Like

```
class Friend:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

you can [instantiate](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) your class by

`friend = Friend('jeremy')`

now just access `name` directly

`print friend.name # jeremy`

There is a good amount to learn about python classes luckily python provides excellent [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for whatever version you are on.

in this example, to create a new friend you need to instantiate it with a name.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is default keyword arguments. The way you have specified it in your example means that `name` is required in the constructor. The way to make it default (and be able to be set after the constructor) would look like this:

```
class Friend(object):

    def __init__(self,name=''):
        self.name = name

    def set_name(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Now your class can be instantiated without a name:

```
aFriend = Friend()
```

As suggested in comments, it is not "considered pythonic" to have setters and getters for a basic attribute. But, if that attribute requires computation, then you can make it a property:

```
class Friend(object):

    def __init__(self, firstname='', lastname=''):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    @property
    def firstname(self):
        return self._first

    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, n):
        self._first = n.capitalize()

    @property
    def lastname(self):
        return self._last

    @lastname.setter
    def lastname(self, n):
        self._last = n.capitalize()        

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname)   

f = Friend('frank')
f.lastname = 'smith'

f.firstname
# 'Frank'

f.lastname
#'Smith'

f.fullname
#'Frank Smith'
```

Comment: It's not considered Pythonic to use setters and getters.

Comment: @GreenMatt: That was not the question. The OP was asking how to make the class so that `name` was not required in the constructor.

Comment: True, it wasn't the question, but that isn't an excuse for encouraging bad practice.

Comment: @GreenMatt: It was not blatantly bad practice because we really didn't know the extent of what the OP would do in those methods, being that the question wasn't really focused on the setters and getters. I don't always like to de-rail the original question, just to teach another point. But thank you for the suggestions. I credit you for the property addition.

Comment: Everything in this answer is correct, but I don't think it answers the question. I think the OP was asking something more like "do I have to declare instance variables before I use them?"

Comment: @Jon-Eric: If that was the question, I totally missed it.

Comment: Actually most previous discussions on SO seem to give properties and setters the hands down

Comment: @Hedde - Blanket statement "properties are unpythonic"? I think it's bad to use them simply to return a hidden attribute, sure. But for the purpose of actually transforming the value, doing a number of checks, updating other members... ? What about a read-only property called `fullname` that simply returns the concatenation of a `first` and `last` set of attributes?

Comment: @Hedde: Putting in properties everywhere just because is definitely unpythonic. But the whole point of properties is so you can avoid writing getters and setters—and, if you later change your mind, turn your attributes into properties, instead of rewriting all of your client code. That's _very_ pythonic.